# chrome.history.getVisits not listing all URLs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to list all the links which are not visited yet from a list of URLs (Array) in Chrome Extension. But my below function is returning only one URL. Where I am doing wrong?

```
function remove_visited(urls, fn) {
    var links = urls,
    unvisitedUrls = [],
    done = false;
    console.log(urls);

    var checkUrl = function(d) {
        var url = d;
        console.log(url);
        return function(visitItems) {
            if (visitItems && visitItems.length > 0) {
                unvisitedUrls.push(url);
            }
            links.splice(links.indexOf(url));
            if(links.length <= 0) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    links.forEach(function(d) {
        chrome.history.getVisits(d, checkUrl(d));
    });

    fn(links);
}
```

Ref: [Wrangling Asynchronous chrome.history calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11992817/395703)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably missunderstood the meaning (and inner workings) of an asynchronous call.

I would propose the following approach:

1. Provide a list of URLs and a callback to be executed with a list of unvisited URLs as argument (after the history check has been completed for all URLs).
2. For each URL in the original list:
   a. Check if it has been visited (and add it to the list of unvisited URLs if so).
   b. Increment a `checkedURLs` counter.
   c. Check if all URLs have been (asynchronously) checked, i.e. `checkedURLs` equals the length of the original URL list.
3. When you detect that all URLs have been checked (see *2.c.*), execute the specified callback (see *1.*), passing the list of unvisited URLs as argument.

---

Some sample code for a demo extension:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Demo",
    "version": "0.0",

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": { "default_title": "Demo Extension" },
    "permissions": ["history"]
}
```

**background.js:**

```
/* List of URLs to check against */
var urlList = [
    "http://stackoverflow.com/",
    "http://qwertyuiop.asd/fghjkl",
    "https://www.google.com/",
    "https://www.qwertyuiop.asd/fghjkl"
];

/* Callback to be executed after all URLs have been checked */
var onCheckCompleted = function(unvisitedURLs) {
    console.log("The following URLs have not been visited yet:");
    unvisitedURLs.forEach(function(url) {
        console.log("    " + url);
    });
    alert("History check complete !\n"
          + "Check console log for details.");
}

/* Check all URLs in <urls> and call <callback> when done */
var findUnvisited = function(urls, callback) {
    var unvisitedURLs = [];
    var checkedURLs = 0;

    /* Check each URL... */
    urls.forEach(function(url) {
        chrome.history.getVisits({ "url": url }, function(visitItems) {
            /* If it has not been visited, add it to <unvisitedURLs> */
            if (!visitItems || (visitItems.length == 0)) {
                unvisitedURLs.push(url);
            }

            /* Increment the counter of checked URLs */
            checkedURLs++;

            /* If this was the last URL to be checked, 
               execute <callback>, passing <unvisitedURLs> */
            if (checkedURLs == urls.length) {
                callback(unvisitedURLs);
            }
        });
    });
}

/* Bind <findUnvisited> to the browser-action */
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    findUnvisited(urlList, onCheckCompleted);
});
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. It is working perfect. I need to learn more on "asynchronous call". If possible could you please provide some good online tutorials links?

Comment: I don'y know any tutorial on the subject (it is more like "get the idea behind it, then pactice to get the hang of it"). For a short explanation see a couple of answers from **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node)**. Take a look **[here](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/6040-what-is-asynchronous-programming.html)** for a more in-depth (possibly redantant) look.